# CSS photo grid layout issue

Tags: html, css, image, css-grid

Recently, I have decided to program my website from scratch after some cost analysis with wix, and realizing it is WAY too expensive in comparison to hosting the website and making it myself.

On my homepage, I am trying to display 4 images in a photo grid layout. However, every time I try to input the CSS command :

```
.photogrid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 300px 300px 300px;
}
```

applying to this div of images

````
 <div class=”photogrid”>
    <img src="/Users/dominicsinicrope/Documents/Website/Img gallery/Personal Stationery.png">
    <img src="/Users/dominicsinicrope/Documents/Website/Img gallery/BJW stationery.png">
    <img src="/Users/dominicsinicrope/Documents/Website/Img gallery/Canvas Tote Bag MockUp.png">
    <img src="/Users/dominicsinicrope/Documents/Website/Img gallery/Flyover Coffee Bags.png">
  </div>```
````

I get a list of images stacked up on top of each other, instead of a 3x2 photo grid layout. Any help on this?

Comment: You can view the eventual intended look of the photo grid on my current free wixsite which I am using as a prototype: domsinicrope.wixsite.com/domsinicrope

Comment: The code you include are in a row rather than stacked. Its not what you want either but if we're not seeing the same thing you might have other CSS is affecting the display and could affect any solutions also. Do you have anything else that could be causing this? Also, if you are not familiar with CSS grids (it can be a lot to get your head around if you are starting with it) then I suggest taking a look at Bootstrap grids - it is much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this CSS:

```
.photogrid img {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: 300px 300px 300px;
```

}

Comment: there is no difference between that and what I put up?

Comment: This is trying to turning the images themselves into a grid display - that isn't going to work!

Comment: Try with this CSS:

    .photogrid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 5vw);
    grid-gap: 15px;
}

.photogrid img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

Comment: @DeepSojitra It is not working, I have only one column and there is no grid gap either.

Comment: @FluffyKitten what do you suggest I do then?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. All I did was create a separate div within "photogrid" and all was well.